# Passing external parameter keeping implicit parameter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, parameter-passing, qgis

I'm coding a python plugin for qgis 3.

Basically I'm trying to get a feature when the user click on it.

```
mapTool.featureIdentified.connect(onFeatureIdentified)
```

so in the function **onfeatureIdentified**

```
def onFeatureIdentified(feature):
        print("feature selected : "+ str(feature.id()))
```

The method featureIdentified pass an implicit paramater.

> void QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature::featureIdentified     (   const QgsFeature
>   &         )    void QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature::featureIdentified  (
>     QgsFeatureId        )

My problem is that I want to pass an other parameter to the function (I want to close my windows when a feature is identified)
like that :

```
mapTool.featureIdentified.connect(onFeatureIdentified(window))

def onFeatureIdentified(feature,window):
            print("feature selected : "+ str(feature.id()))
            window.quit()
```

By doing that, the window parameter overwrite the implicit parameter of the native method.

How should I do ?

Comment: Try `mapTool.featureIdentified.connect(lambda f: onFeatureIdentified(f, window))`.

Comment: Wow it seems to work. I feel dumb because I used lambda for other function and I ignored it would work. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 ways to do it :

- use of lambda function (credit to acw1668) to pass the second parameter

  ```
  mapTool.featureIdentified.connect(lambda feature: onFeatureIdentified(feature, window))
  ```

  then

  ```
  def onFeatureIdentified(feature,window):
  ```
- If you use class (like me) :

  define you window in the **__init__** function of your class then always refer the window by **self.window**

  ```
  mapTool.featureIdentified.connect(self.onFeatureIdentified)
  ```

  then

  ```
  def onFeatureIdentified(self,feature):
  print("feature selected : "+ str(feature.id()))
  self.window.quit()
  ```

  The first parameter will be self then it will pass the native parameter of the function